# Creating 2 objects with has_one association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to get some info about creating new objects in Rails with validation. For example, there is the following code:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    # some actions: redirect, render, etc
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

But if there is 2 models with has_one association, for example Club and Place. I need to create both this objects from params in the same 'create' action, because I've got the same form for inputing data for it(`params[:club]` and `params[:club][:place]`). I don't know how I should save this objects, because for building a place (`@club.build_place(params[:club][:place])`) I should save @club in database. Please, give me example of the code for my problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're creating multiple objects from a single form you'd probably be best off putting this logic into a "Form Object"...  See the article "7 Patterns to Refactor Fat ActiveRecord Models" from the CodeClimate blog found here (look for Section #3 on extracting Form Objects): http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models.

Railscasts also has a good episode on form objects, though it is a "Pro Episode" (i.e. requires subscription). http://railscasts.com/episodes/416-form-objects

In short, you create a custom model including some of the necessary ActiveModel modules then create a custom save method, e.g. (this is directly from the article which has a lot of great advice).

```
class Signup
  include Virtus

  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_reader :user
  attr_reader :company

  attribute :name, String
  attribute :company_name, String
  attribute :email, String

  validates :email, presence: true
  # … more validations …

  # Forms are never themselves persisted
  def persisted?
    false
  end

  def save
    if valid?
      persist!
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end

private

  def persist!
    @company = Company.create!(name: company_name)
    @user = @company.users.create!(name: name, email: email)
  end
end
```

This gives you much more control and a much cleaner interface.

Comment: Thanks, very good suggestion. Also, please, tell me - your example of code add errors to models or not? I want to show information about errors in view...

Comment: Yes, by including the `ActiveModel::Validations` module you get the same validation behavior you'd get with an ActiveRecord model, which will add errors to your model.  Which you can then display in the view.

Comment: Can you tell me also, please, can accepts_nested_attributes_for help me in my task?

Comment: Yes, you could also use accepts_nested_attributes_for, however that is what the "Form Object" is designed to save you from... Just check all the Stack Overflow questions on troubleshooting accepts_nested_attributes_for...