# How to create a Rails form that works with multiple resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a sort of set up wizard form that does nothing more than provide a few fields from a few different models to give you the ability to create more than one model at once. I'm assuming there is a Rails-way to combine multiple "resources" within a single form, but I'm not sure how to do that. How can I create a form which provides fields from multiple models, while taking advantage of as many built-in helpers as possible?

Comment: You might check out one of Jay Fields' blog posts about using the Presenter idea.  In this post, he builds a form for 3 objects.  You might be able to use it as a guideline.  http://blog.jayfields.com/2007/03/rails-presenter-pattern.html

Comment: See this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20102973/creating-2-objects-with-has-one-association-in-rails/20103057#20103057

Comment: We've done this before - let me write answer for you

Answer (score 0):

There is a good [tutorial here](http://iain.nl/backends-in-rails-3-1) on how to do this

This works really well if you use the likes of [inherited resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources):

---

**Partial**

```
#app/helpers/application_helper.rb
def attributes(resource)
    resource ||= resource_class
    resource.attribute_names - %w(id created_at updated_at)
end

#app/views/shared/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for resource do |f| %>
    <% attributes(resource).each do |attr| %>
        <%= f.text_field attr.to_sym, placeholder: attr.name, value: attr.value %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

#app/views/controller/new.html.erb
<%= render partial: "shared/form", locals: {resource: <<model class>>} %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I don't think this quite answers the question. Your solution depends on another gem, and your code sample only shows creating form fields dynamically based on the model attributes. I'm trying to figure out how to combine two models into one form and keep Rails happy.